# Scroll to bottom of UITableView on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

My view controller has a UITableView, but it isn't the main view. I find now that when the user tries to scroll to the bottom, the scroll view doesn't consider the height of the bottom bar.

I could fix this by turning off **Extend Edges: Under Bottom Bars**, but that gets rid of the semi-transulecent effect. I'd rather manually add the extra height to the tableview. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: i think the contentInsets property of UIScrollView is maybe the right place to look at. (UIScrollView is the superclass of UITableView.)

Comment: You're right. I was discouraged by some early experiments into this, but when I tried again after your poke it worked. :) I posted this as an answer; if you want to write up one, I'll happily delete mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the UITableView's `contentInset`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIEdgeInsets edges = _tableView.contentInset;
    edges.bottom = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height;
    _tableView.contentInset = edges;
}
```

Thanks to Michael above.